# Creating collabsible tree with xml and xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, tree

I am currently looking for a solution to the problem above. Creating a table with recursive templates works just fine, but I reallly would prefer to have a collapsible tree as the XML files might get very huge...

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: You couldnt be more general and vague I think.

Comment: I got xml files that represent a file structure with directories and files. files and directories got properties from a subversion system. I would like to have a tree that is collabsible. As i said the file and directory structure might get very huge.

Comment: simply sth like the normal xml representation in a browser, bu i would like to add custom colors according to the properties from the svn system

Comment: Well collapsing/expanding is usually done within the browser with script manipulating the CSS display property. Your XSLT would simply need to generate the HTML plus CSS plus Javascript.

Comment: When you open a XML file in a browser there already is a collapsible tree structure. I just would need a possibility to customize colors to leaves if some conditions become true and propagate that to the parents

Comment: You cannot customize this as it is a built in view your browser has provided. You would need to re-implement this view via xslt/css/html and customize it to your liking

Comment: @Brandon - actually, in some browsers at least you can customize the built-in view of XML. E.g. in Firefox there is a default XSLT stylesheet that's used to produce the XML pretty-printed view. You can modify this stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for the XSLT stylesheet Firefox uses to display XML as a collapsible tree, but I can't find it. The best I could find was [this old one from IE5](http://web.archive.org/web/19991130022033/http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/xml/samples/defaultss/defaultss.xsl). It will get you started.

Oh wait... here is the [XSLT stylesheet](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/xml/document/resources/XMLPrettyPrint.xsl) from Mozilla, and the [CSS is here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/xml/document/resources/XMLPrettyPrint.css). I don't think it gives you everything you need for collapsing nodes... see also the [XBL here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/xml/document/resources/XMLPrettyPrint.xml). But again it's a start.

You can also try looking at the [Chrome extension XML Tree](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb). You can download the crx file and open it as an archive. The archive contains a javascript file, which includes an XSLT stylesheet embedded as a string. That XSLT should meet the need you've expressed.

Further references, from the js in the Chrome extension:

- [Arjan van Bentem's idea](https://superuser.com/questions/972/displaying-xml-in-chrome-browser)
- [XML Tree by TarquinWJ](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/operaStuff/userJavaScript.html)
- [Pretty XML tree by Jakub Roztocil](http://blog.webkitchen.cz/pretty-xml-tree)

However if the XML files really might get huge, you might consider some kind of paging technique, or using [HTML5 web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/), rather than let the browser freeze while XSLT renders the XML into HTML. Or, run the XSLT transform outside of the browser, and just open the HTML output in the browser.

Comment: @Brandon, it's not very easy to find. Last time I tried it, which was probably a couple of years ago, the stylesheet was zipped up somewhere in a resource not searchable by ordinary methods. In order to customize it, you have to learn something about XUL and developing extensions for Fx. I.e. it's more complicated than just specifying an XSLT stylesheet as an option somewhere. But it is doable.